# Gmod fading doors dosnt work after I reload my savegame

Tags: steam, mods, garrys-mod

I am playing Gmod with the popular "fading doors" addon.

I make a few doors and as soon as I exit my game and load it again, all the doors no longer function with their corresponding key-bindings.

Is anyone else having this problem, and does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually an extremely common problem. Whether intentional or a part of the code, fading doors do not rebind to their respective keys upon reloading a save and also when rejoining a server.

The only way I can recommend to fix it is to manually go to each door and then recreate it as a fading door. I understand this is painful, but I have not found any other solution for this problem.